# Getting Error Access denied while consuming WSDL endpoint

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I need to access **web service which required HTTP basic authentication** and I consumed successfully using SoapUI.
[SoapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHxyj.png)

Now I need to implement in .net.

I created a new C# Console project in Visual Studio and added a web reference for https://itestapi.tracelink.com/soap/snx/snrequest?wsdl

Below is my code and I am getting **Access Denied**

C# code

```
 ServiceReference1.snrequestClient snx = new ServiceReference1.snrequestClient();
            snx.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "abc@gmail.com";
            snx.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xyz@2018";

            ServiceReference1.objectKey objectKey = new ServiceReference1.objectKey
            {
                Name = ServiceReference1.objectIdentifierType.GTIN,
                Value = "1111111"
            };
            ServiceReference1.ReferenceDocuments ReferenceDocuments = new ServiceReference1.ReferenceDocuments();
            snx.serialNumbersRequest("11111", "11111", ServiceReference1.idType.GS1_SER, ServiceReference1.encodingType.SGTIN, 2, objectKey, "", ReferenceDocuments);
```

App.config

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="snrequestPortBinding">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="snrequestPortBinding1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://itestapi.tracelink.com:443/soap/snx/snrequest"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="snrequestPortBinding"
            contract="ServiceReference1.snrequest" name="snrequestPort" />
    </client>
```